# JDesktopPane placement

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have a JDesktopPane and want to display JInternalFrames in a grid style without overlaying frames. The dymensions of the frames will vary so their location should be assigned dynamically. I could store the coordinates of the last placed frame but frames can be moved, minimized or closed.. Is their an easy way of placing internal frames in a tidy way? e.g., using a Layout?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/2e1b14bcad9bd7fa) that may offer some guidance. It uses `setLocation()` and an offset.

Answer (score 2):

The `DesktopManager` class is responsible for managing the internal frames.

You should be able to override the `openFrame()` method to initially position the frame when it is added to the desktop.

There are also methods on dragging that you might be able to override to prevent the overlapping of frames.