# How to bring jinternalframe to front from all opened jinternalframes?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jinternalframe

This is my source code. 
I can't get my `JInternalframe` to the front. 
I have tried many codes out there, but nothing worked.

```
    private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    boolean b = true;
    JInternalFrame[] j = jDesktopPane1.getAllFrames();
    no = new NewOrder();

    for (JInternalFrame Ji : j) {
        if (Ji.isShowing()) {
            b = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!b) {
      no.requestFocus(true);
    } else {
        dm = jDesktopPane1.getDesktopManager();
        jDesktopPane1.add(no);
        dm.setBoundsForFrame(no, (jDesktopPane1.getWidth() - no.getWidth()) / 2, (jDesktopPane1.getHeight() - no.getHeight()) / 2, no.getWidth(), no.getHeight());
        dm.openFrame(no);
        no.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

and

```
NewOrder no = new NewOrder();

if (no.isShowing()) {
    no.toFront();
} else {
    lo.LoadInterfaces(no, jDesktopPane1);
}
```

Can any body please explain me why this was happened?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`setSelected()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setSelected-boolean-) method of [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html); a complete example is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930245/230513). For convenience, invoke the method from an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513).

Addendum: A typical implementation might look like this.

```
class MyFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    private Action action;

    MyFrame(…) {
        …
        action = new AbstractAction(name) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    MyFrame.this.setSelected(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return action;
    }
}
```

Comment: I sense you got it working; if you still have problems, please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your approach.

Comment: I sense some ambivalence; I've abstracted the essential usage above.

Comment: what you are using for name value?

Comment: Just a `String`; same as the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6930245/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I found it..

```
    NewOrder no = new NewOrder();

    if (no.isShowing()) {
        no.toFront();
    } else {
        lo.LoadInterfaces(no, jDesktopPane1);
    }
```

It was just remove the initialization.. And do initialization and declaration at once. Can any body please explain me why this was happened. Please.

Comment: `toFront()` conditionally calls `setSelected()`.

Comment: @Catalina Island is that affect different in the working schedule?

Comment: The internal frame, or the corresponding icon, must be showing to allow selection.